# Karma Test running after executing tests screen goes blank

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

after running ng test my test runner begins executing all the tests but afterwards just goes blank. See image below.

[image]

My Karma Config:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

my Package.json devDeps:

```
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.0.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
"karma": "~1.4.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
"protractor": "~5.1.0",
"ts-node": "~2.0.0",
"tslint": "~4.5.0",
"typescript": "~2.2.0"
```

}

Could it be a version issue? Maybe upgrade my Karma version? This was installed via cli, and I believe it was working earlier but somehow it has come to this.

Comment: As far as I remember, every time the tests are all completed and the browser is idle, the screen goes blank, that's the expected behavior

Comment: So if all tests are passed the screen goes blank? I remember being able to see all the results after the tests are complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of npm version dependencies:-

```
 npm i --save-dev jasmine-core@latest
 npm i --save karma-jasmine@latest
```

Install these two dependencies this will resolve your issue.

Complete Package.json [FYR]

```
{
  "name": "karma-coverage-sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The culprit is the `client.clearContext` option in
[the Karma configuration](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html) :

> If true, Karma clears the context window upon the completion of running the tests. If false, Karma does not clear the context window upon the completion of running the tests. Setting this to false is useful when embedding a Jasmine Spec Runner Template.

To avoid blanking the screen, disable this option, like so (karma.conf.js):

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        /* ... */
        client: {
            clearContext: false
        }
        /* ... */
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue. Setting the clearContext flag didn't make any difference.

For me though, it was only happening when using the --code-coverage argument. I was able to fix it by specifying the reporters manually:

```
karma start --code-coverage=true --reporters=progress,coverage-istanbul,kjhtml
```

Answer (score 0):

One more case where this issue happens is if you have listed browsers which are not installed on PC.
Example: in your karma config file you have:
`browsers: ["Chrome", "Firefox", "IE"],`
but on your machine you do not have firefox, you would also get idle tests.